# Cookies set secureflag to true

Tags: http, cookies

What happens if `secureflag` is set to `true` in case of http requests? Should it be set to true only if requests are being coming from https clients? This blog [here](http://support.filecatalyst.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/209/0/securing-session-cookies-in-tomcat-with--httponly-and-securetrue) says so.

If someone here can please explain what are the disadvantages of setting this flag to true, that will be great help.

Answer (score 2):

By setting 'secureflag' is true , you are insisting the browser to transmit your cookies  only over the SSL. In case, if it is non SSL, then the Cookies will not be shared. For better understanding [read this doc](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag).